# Consume web service with DJANGO

Tags: python, django, web-services, soap

I have a django application to show some data from my database (ORACLE), but now I need to show some data from a web service.

I need to build a form based in the request of the web service, and show the response of the web service.

I googling to expose my app as a web service and send and retrieve XML data.

But I am very confused and I don't know where to start or which django package to use(PyXML,DJANGO REST).

I am not sure if I need to build a web API or I can consume the web service without the web api.

Can someone give some advices to achieve this task.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to build a web API if all you want to do is consume someone else's API. Just retrieve the data - with something like `requests` - and use it in your Django app.

Comment: the question is how to do that. how can I send the request from a form and how to retrieve the data.